# @ControllerAdvice methods seem to bypass interceptors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` with some central exception handling for my api.  One of the exceptions it handles is the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` which gets thrown when a request method parameter annotated with `@Valid`, fails validation.

In my application, I also have a CORS interceptor setup which adds the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to the servlet response when the request is successful.  However, it seems that when validation fails on the parameter annotated with `@Valid`, my interceptor gets bypassed.  My exception handler needs to send back error information for form fields that are invalid so they can be dealt with in the browser.

Just wondering if this is normal behaviour that my interceptor gets bypassed when an exception is thrown, or if I'm missing some configuration in the `@ControllerAdvice` class.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a duplicate.  I'm already handling my exception the way that it's described in the accepted response of that post.  My problem is more of a CORS request problem where my interceptor isn't decorating the servlet response when my exception handler gets called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed normal behavior.

From the javadoc of [`HandlerInterceptor.postHandle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#postHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView-)

> Intercept the execution of a handler. Called after `HandlerAdapter` actually invoked the handler, but before the `DispatcherServlet` renders the view. Can expose additional model objects to the view via the given `ModelAndView`.
>   `DispatcherServlet` processes a handler in an execution chain, consisting of any number of interceptors, with the handler itself at the end. With this method, each interceptor can post-process an execution, getting applied in inverse order of the execution chain.

Arguably the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown before the method is actually called, it is called in preparing the actual method call. Actually the `postHandle` is only executed after successful execution/invocation of the method. In case of an exception only the `preHandle` and `afterCompletion` methods are called.

Comment: Thanks!  I had indeed implemented the postHandle method.  I changed my code to implement the preHandle method and now the header is successfully added to the response in the event the exception is thrown.